# How to submit a simple_form with stimulus remote true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form-for, stimulusjs

I have a really simple form

```
  span data-controller='reassignment'
    = simple_form_for some_model, remote: true, html: {'data-target': 'reassignment.form'} do |f|
      = f.association :user,
        collection: User.all,
        label: false,
        include_blank: 'Unassigned',
        input_html: { \
          "data-target": "reassignment.user", \
          "data-action": "change->reassignment#submitForm" \
          }
```

now my stimulus looks like

```
import { Controller } from 'stimulus'

export default class extends Controller {

  static targets = ['user', 'form']

  submitForm(){
    this.formTarget.submit()
  }

  onPostSuccess(event) {
    console.log("success!")
  }
}
```

The forms submits but it does not respect the `remote: true`.

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick.

```
import { Controller } from 'stimulus'
import Rails from "@rails/ujs"

export default class extends Controller {

  static targets = ['user', 'form']

  submitForm(){
    Rails.fire(this.formTarget, 'submit')
  }

  onPostSuccess(event) {
    console.log("success!")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a preventDefault on the submit. You need to keep the button from doing it's normal thing.

```
submitForm(e){
  e.preventDefault()
  this.formTarget.submit()
}
```